# Bash, trim a "complicated" string to obtain a new string

Tags: string, bash, trim

I have a txt file contains many strings(every string lies in a line). A typical string has this shape:

```
sno_Int-INT1_Exp-INT2_INT3.fits.fz_ovsc_rms_D4_D5_D6_D7_D8_D9
```

In the above string, "INT1", "INT2" and "INT3" are all integer types and their values might variant for each string in the text file, "D4 - 9" are double type(not fixed value also).

What I need to do is to change the above string to a new string like :

```
INT3_ovsc_rms_D4_D5_D6_D7_D8_D9
```

Can anybody tell me how to do it ?

Thanks!

Comment: How about not using Bash?  Any preference among Ruby, Python, Perl?

Comment: @JohnZwinck, Thanks for comment. Currently, I prefer to do it in Bash since I'm in the middle of a project which was started with Bash.

Comment: Is the string `fz_ovsc_rms_` fixed?

Comment: @user2740039: Provide some real examples of input and output

Comment: @AdrianFrühwirth, `fz_ovsc_rms_` is fixed.

Comment: @anubhava, sure, `INT3` is a runID, and I don't like to put all string  because of two reasons : (1)it's not necessary; (2)there is no enough space to display it on a button of a website.

Comment: @anubhava, a real string is like `sno_Int-300_Exp-1000_1051.fits.fz_ovsc_rms_10.6_2.35_53.2_0_5.92_2.14`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

input=$1
left=${input%%.*}
right=${input#*.fz_}
int3=${left##*_}
output=${int3}_${right}

echo "${output}"
```

.

```
$ ./foo.sh sno_Int-INT1_Exp-INT2_INT3.fits.fz_ovsc_rms_D4_D5_D6_D7_D8_D9
INT3_ovsc_rms_D4_D5_D6_D7_D8_D9

$ ./foo.sh sno_Int-300_Exp-1000_1051.fits.fz_ovsc_rms_10.6_2.35_53.2_0_5.92_2.14
1051_ovsc_rms_10.6_2.35_53.2_0_5.92_2.14
```

Depending on your real input this might break horribly, though.

Comment: "Depending on your real input this might break horribly" applies to most Bash seen in the wild....

Comment: @JohnZwinck Agreed, but one *can* write idiomatic and "beautiful" bash  with proper error handling. It just doesn't happen very often ...

Comment: @JohnZwinck, Thanks a lot for your contribution ! I like your solution not only it solved my asking but your code is very intuitive for me. Merci, :-) .

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to do this in pure Bash, you'll need to split the string by setting IFS and then using `read` with a "here string".  For details, see here: [How do I split a string on a delimiter in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/918886/how-do-i-split-a-string-on-a-delimiter-in-bash)

You will probably need to split it multiple times--once by underscore and then by dash, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind awk:

```
echo sno_Int-INT1_Exp-INT2_INT3.fits.fz_ovsc_rms_D4_D5_D6_D7_D8_D9 | awk -F_ 'BEGIN{OFS="_"}{sub(/.fits.fz/,"",$4);print $4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9,$10,$11,$12}'
```

INT3_ovsc_rms_D4_D5_D6_D7_D8_D9

Comment: Hi, Mark, thanks for your post. Your code run smoothly on my machine either. Unfortunately, I have issued the green icon of answer to somebody else... Thanks again !

Answer (score 0):

This awk should work:

```
s='1000_1051.fits.fz_ovsc_rms_10.6_2.35_53.2_0_5.92_2.14'
awk -F'[_.]' 'NR==1{i3=$2;next} {printf "%s%s%s", i3, RS, $0}' RS='_ovsc_rms' <<< "$s"
1051_ovsc_rms_10.6_2.35_53.2_0_5.92_2.14
```

Comment: your code is cool. However, on my machine, I need to change the `$2` in the `{i3=$2}` to `$4` to get the same as yours(and I expected). Otherwise, what I obtained on my machine is : `Int-300_ovsc_rms_10.6_2.35_53.2_0_5.92_2.14` .